# javap -l option cannot display line number info

Tags: java, javap

The `javap` command has several options, one of them is `-l`, which can print line number and local variable tables. Suppose a java program has been compiled successfully and there is the file "Main.class", so running `javap -l Main` can produce something like:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);

LineNumberTable:
 line 100: 0
 line 101: 27
 line 275: 54

LocalVariableTable:
 Start Length Slot Name Signature
 0     55     0    args  [Ljava/lang/String;
```

However, I'm using this `javap -l xxx` command on the class files of one java program, but the area of line number and local variable table is empty (which shouldn't be). The `javap` command and other options such as `-s`, `-verbose` works fine, but only the line info area corresponding to the `-l` option is empty.

Has anyone ever encountered such weird case?

Comment: Guess the line numbers have been stripped, not weird at all, means it was built without debug info and/or obfuscated.

Comment: Please isolate the smallest possible test case you can which displays the problem, and post the source code which generates such a class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use -g to compile your code, otherwise the line numbers are not kept (akin to the stack trace displaying "compiled code" instead of the line number)

Comment: +1 See -g option in http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: By default Oracle's JDK does keep line numbers, but if the code was compiled with -g:none then it will not include this.

Comment: Thank you guys. The answer as well as comments help a lot.